# PowerBI: Power Query: Dealing with changing column names due to pivots

Tags: powerbi, pivot, powerquery

For a report I am making. I have a date column. I extract the months from that column and then pivot the months.

So for example I might have a table like:

| Part# | Month | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 10 |
| 1 | 3 | 10 |
| 1 | 4 | 10 |
| 1 | 5 | 10 |
| 1 | 6 | 10 |

Which when I pivot it becomes:

| Part# | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |

I then rename the columns along with doing a few other tasks like creating a column of maximums.
However, since the data I pull is only for 6-months worth. These columns names will change.
In the future it may be:

| Part# | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |

So a line like:

```
Table.ReplaceValue(#"Pivoted Column",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"})
```

is going to create an error when the columns are 4,5,6,7,8,9. Is there a way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to manually code a step to rename the columns after your pivot.

This M code pulls a table like the one in your example from the current workbook in Excel, then pivots as you describe, then renames the columns to Part#, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, and 6th. Yes, I said it renames to Part#, even though it doesn't really change that column name. Be sure to include Part# in the list coded in the step even though the Part# name isn't really changing, because you need to account for all column names extracted by Table.ColumnNames. Replace 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, and 6th with *your* desired column names.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Month", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Month", type text}}, "en-US")[Month]), "Month", "Qty"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column", List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"),{"Part#", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th"}}))
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

List.Zip interweaves two lists together. Here, it interweaves Part# from the original column names (those in the "Pivoted Column" step's table), then Part# from the list coded into #"Renamed Columns, then the next original column name (1 from your first example or 4 from your second example), then 1st from the column list coded into #"Renamed Columns, then the next original column name (2 from your first example or 5 from your second example), then 2nd from the column list coded into #"Renamed Columns, and so forth. This sets up the list needed for Table.RenameColumns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TableColumNames` to get a list of column names, then you can transform that list. So for your example, you could use something like:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Pivoted Column",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"),1))
```